# QFrame round border transparent background

Tags: qt, transparent, qwidget, qtstylesheets, qframe

I'm creating a round context menu using `QFrame`.

To make round corner, I used Qt style sheet :

```
this->setStyleSheet("QFrame#ShareContextMenu{
    background-color:rgb(255,255,255);
    border-width:1px;
    border-color :rgb(0,0,0);
    border-radius:10px;
    border-style:solid;}

QPushButton{background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);}
QPushButton::hover{background-color:rgba(125,125,125,50); border-radius:5px;}");
```

How can I remove the white background marked with red circles in this picture?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you cannot resolve the problem using style sheets. `QMenu` is a rectangular top-level widget.

Is `this` your `QMenu`? If so, try this:

```
this->setWindowFlags(this->windowFlags() | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```

Replace `this` by your instantiated `QMenu` object.

Of course, you could also use [setMask](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setMask-2) to hide the required region. For example:

```
QRegion region (menu->x(),
                menu->y(),
                menu->sizeHint().width(),
                menu->sizeHint().height(),
                QRegion::Ellipse);
menu->setMask(region);
```