# Message with rounded corners with Qt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt5, pyside2

I'm trying to create a widget like the message box at the bottom in this picture:

[image: img]

It should overlay the main widget. I have 2 ways to do this:

- With a QFrame and rounded corners
- With a mask

But there's a problem with each of them:

- The QFrame approach seems like a better idea but the background isn't transparent. This means that even though the borders have a radius, the background is still making it a rectangle. It's somewhat noticeable in the picture. Unfortunately, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491282/qframe-round-border-transparent-background) doesn't seem to work. Same for `self.setStyleSheet("background:transparent")`.

[image: img]

- The mask looks very pixelated, and it's not the expected behavior because the mask used can only be a simple QRegion. These don't have squircles, which would be ideal.

[image: img]

Here's what the code looks like:

```py
class Message(QFrame):
    """
    A temporary message to show information in the GUI.
    """

    def __init__(self, msg: str, *args, destroy_time: int = None):
        super().__init__(*args)

        # Main layout
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)

        # The label
        label = QLabel(msg)
        label.setFont(Fonts.text)
        label.setStyleSheet(f"color: {Colors.fg};"
                            "padding: 20px;")
        self.layout.addWidget(label)
        self.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: {Colors.bg};"
                           "border-radius: 30px;")

        #  region = QRegion(self.x(), self.y(), self.sizeHint().width(),
                         #  self.sizeHint().height(), QRegion.Ellipse)
        #  self.setMask(region)

        self.adjustSize()
```

Edit for S. Nick: Your solution only works if the Message widget is the only widget in the application. The intended usage is this:

```py
class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, player: QWidget):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.addWidget(player)

        msg = Message("I can't make this work", self)
```

where `player` is the main widget, and the message overlays it when it appears. Imagine it being an image, which is overlayed by the message. Sorry for not explaining myself correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Message(QWidget):   #(QFrame): #
    def __init__(self, msg: str, *args, destroy_time: int = None):
        super().__init__(*args)

        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint) # <---
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)                   # <---

        Colors_fg = "#fa0"
        Colors_bg = "rgba( 155, 155, 155, 150)"                          # <---

        # Main layout
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)

        # The label
        label = QLabel(msg, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        label.setFont(QFont("Times", 17, QFont.Bold, italic=True))       #(Fonts.text)
        label.setStyleSheet(f"color: {Colors_fg};"
                             "padding: 0px;")
        self.layout.addWidget(label)

# vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.setStyleSheet(f"background-color: {Colors_bg};"  
                            "min-height: 70px;"
                            "max-height: 70px;"
                            "width: 200px;"
                            "border-radius: 30px;"
                           )
# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        self.adjustSize()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Message("Hello \nWorld")
    w.resize(400, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

---

**Update**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Message(QDialog):      #(QFrame):
    def __init__(self, msg: str, *args, destroy_time: int = None):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | 
                            Qt.FramelessWindowHint |
                            Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint) 
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)                   

        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.widget.setObjectName('Custom_Widget')
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget)

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self.widget)
        self.layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(
            40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum), 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(QPushButton('r', self, 
                                          clicked=self.accept, 
                                          objectName='closeButton'), 0, 1)
        # The label
        label = QLabel(msg)
        label.setFont(QFont("Times", 17, QFont.Bold, italic=True))         #((Fonts.text)
        self.layout.addWidget(label, 2, 0, 5, 2, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)                           
        self.adjustSize()

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.old_Pos    = event.globalPos()
        self.old_width  = self.width()
        self.old_height = self.height()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if (event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton): 
            delta = QPoint (event.globalPos() - self.old_Pos)
            if (self.old_Pos.x() > self.x() + self.old_width - 20) or \
               (self.old_Pos.y() > self.y() + self.old_height - 20):
                w = self.old_width+delta.x()  if self.old_width+delta.x()  > 500 else 500
                h = self.old_height+delta.y() if self.old_height+delta.y() > 400 else 400
                self.setFixedSize(w, h)
            else:
                self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
                self.old_Pos = event.globalPos()


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, player: QWidget):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.addWidget(player)

        self.msg = Message("I can't make this work")#, self)        
        self.msg.show()


Stylesheet = """
#Custom_Widget {
    background: rgba( 155, 155, 155, 150);
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ff2025;                   
}
#closeButton {
    min-width: 36px;
    min-height: 36px;
    font-family: "Webdings";
    qproperty-text: "r";
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#closeButton:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    background: red;
}
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)

    w = MainWindow(QPushButton("player"))
    w.resize(400, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

---

**Update 2**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class Message(QFrame):      # QDialog
    def __init__(self, msg: str, *args, destroy_time: int = None):
        super().__init__(*args)
#        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | 
#                            Qt.FramelessWindowHint #|Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint) 
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)                   

        self.widget = QWidget(self)
        self.widget.setObjectName('Custom_Widget')
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget)

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self.widget)
        self.layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(
            40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum), 0, 0)
        self.layout.addWidget(QPushButton('r', self, 
#                                          clicked=self.accept, 
                                          clicked=self.close, 
                                          objectName='closeButton'), 0, 1)
        # The label
        label = QLabel(msg)
        label.setFont(QFont("Times", 15, QFont.Bold, italic=True))         #((Fonts.text)
        self.layout.addWidget(label, 2, 0, 5, 2, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)                           
        self.adjustSize()


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, player: QWidget):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.addWidget(player)
        player.clicked.connect(self._msg)

    def _msg(self):
        self.msg = Message("I can't make this work\nself.msg.setGeometry(10, 10, 480, 150)", self)        
        self.msg.setGeometry(10, 10, 480, 150)
        self.msg.show()


Stylesheet = """
#Custom_Widget {
    background: rgba( 155, 155, 155, 150);
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #ff2025;                   
}
#closeButton {
    min-width: 36px;
    min-height: 36px;
    font-family: "Webdings";
    qproperty-text: "r";
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#closeButton:hover {
    color: #ccc;
    background: red;
}
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)

    w = MainWindow(QPushButton("player"))
    w.resize(500, 400)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, S. Nick. But I didn't explain myself correctly. That will only work if the Message widget is the only one in the application. Please check the edited post for more information.

Comment: @Dewamuval I update the answer, move the Message wherever you want.

Comment: But the thing is that it should be inside the main widget, overlaying the `player` widget. Just like the example picture.

Comment: @Dewamuval I am updating the answer, position the message wherever you want.

Comment: You rock man. Thanks for your persistence and help, have a great day :)